# How to add a rich snippet to single page of products?

Tags: e-commerce, rich-snippets

I have an e-commerce website and I want to add a rich snippet only for this page http://samuelshats.com/kentucky-derby-hats-women. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no rich snippet which applies to that page. [Rich Snippets for Products](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) only applies to pages with a single product on them. Applying schema.org markup to that page will not cause a rich snippet to be shown as there are multiple products on that page.